# Spring form:select multiple selected value?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have this edit form:

[image]

I want that the roles of the user get selected. If this were one-to-many relation I know that I can do something like this:

```
        <form:label path="roles">Roles:</form:label>
        <form:select multiple="true" path="roles">
            <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="rol">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when
                        test="${usuarioEdit.rol.id ==rol.id}">
                        <option value="${rol.id}" selected="selected">${rol.nombre}</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <option value="${rol.id}">${rol.nombre}</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
        <form:errors cssStyle="color:red" path="roles"></form:errors>
```

But this is a many-to-many relation. How can I get selected the options in an edit form?. Is there an easy form?

This code works, but I wonder if spring gives any facilities:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="roles">
            <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="rol">
                <c:set var="isSelected" value="false" />
                <c:forEach items="${rolesUsu}" var="rolUsu">
                    <c:if test="${rolUsu.getRol().getId()==rol.id}">
                        <c:set var="isSelected" value="true" />
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${isSelected}">
                        <option value="${rol.id}" selected="selected">${rol.nombre}</option>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <option value="${rol.id}">${rol.nombre}</option>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:select>
```

**Edit:**

In my controller I have:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "roles",
                new RolCollectionEditor(Set.class, rolDao));

    }
```

RolCollectionEditor:

```
public class RolCollectionEditor extends CustomCollectionEditor {

     private final RolDAO rolDao;


    public RolCollectionEditor(Class<?> collectionType, RolDAO rolDao) {

        super(collectionType);
        this.rolDao = rolDao;

    }

    @Override
    protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
        String rolId = (String) element;

        Rol rol = rolDao.findById(rolId);
        Usuario_Rol usuRol = new Usuario_Rol();

        //Agregamos un usuario vacio temporal
        //y lo sobreescribimos en el controlador
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        usuRol.setUsuario(usuario);
        usuRol.setRol(rol);
        usuRol.setFechaCreacion(new Date());
        usuRol.setFechaModificacion(new Date());
        usuRol.setStatus("activo");

        return usuRol;
    }

}
```

Here Usuario_Rol is an intermediate table for the many to many relation, that have other attributes besides the userId and rolId.

**Edit2:**

Rol class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rol", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "nombre") })
public class Rol implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    @NotNull
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "descripcion")
    private String descripcion;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "fechaCreacion")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @Column(name = "fechaModificacion")
    private Date fechaModificacion;

    @Column(name = "fechaSincronizacion")
    private Date fechaSincronizacion;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "usuarioRol_pk.rol", orphanRemoval = true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Usuario_Rol> usuarios = new HashSet<Usuario_Rol>(0);


    //getters and setters

    @Override
    final public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    final public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Rol))
            return false;
        Rol other = (Rol) obj;
        if (nombre == null) {
            if (other.nombre != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Class Usuario:

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "login"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "correo") })
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@Column(name = "_id")
private String id;

@Column(name = "nombre")
@NotEmpty
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "apellido")
@NotEmpty
private String apellido;

@Column(name = "login")
@Size(min = 4)
@NotEmpty
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 4)
private String password;

@Column(name = "salt")
private String salt;

@Column(name = "correo")
@NotEmpty
@Email
private String correo;

@Column(name = "token")
private String token;

@Column(name = "status")
private String status;

@Column(name = "fechaUltimoLogin")
private Date fechaUltimoLogin;

@Column(name = "fechaCreacion")
private Date fechaCreacion;

@Column(name = "fechaModificacion")
private Date fechaModificacion;

@Column(name = "fechaSincronizacion")
private Date fechaSincronizacion;

@NotEmpty
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "usuarioRol_pk.usuario", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Usuario_Rol> roles = new HashSet<Usuario_Rol>(0);


//constructor, getters and setters.

@Override
final public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((login == null) ? 0 : login.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
final public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof Usuario))
        return false;
    Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
    if (login == null) {
        if (other.login != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!login.equals(other.login))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Intermediate class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario_rol")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "usuarioRol_pk.usuario", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idUsuario")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "usuarioRol_pk.rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idRol")) 
})
public class Usuario_Rol implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private Usuario_RolId usuarioRol_pk = new Usuario_RolId();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "fechaCreacion")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "fechaModificacion")
    private Date fechaModificacion;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "fechaSincronizacion")
    private Date fechaSincronizacion;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    //gettters, setters

    @Override
    final public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((usuarioRol_pk == null) ? 0 : usuarioRol_pk.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    final public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Usuario_Rol))
            return false;
        Usuario_Rol other = (Usuario_Rol) obj;
        if (usuarioRol_pk == null) {
            if (other.usuarioRol_pk != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!usuarioRol_pk.equals(other.usuarioRol_pk))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Usuario_RolId:

```
@Embeddable
public class Usuario_RolId implements Serializable{

    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario usuario;

    @ManyToOne
    private Rol rol;

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public Rol getRol() {
        return rol;
    }
    public void setRol(Rol rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }


    @Override
    final public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((rol == null) ? 0 : rol.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((usuario == null) ? 0 : usuario.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    final public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Usuario_RolId))
            return false;
        Usuario_RolId other = (Usuario_RolId) obj;
        if (rol == null) {
            if (other.rol != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!rol.equals(other.rol))
            return false;
        if (usuario == null) {
            if (other.usuario != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!usuario.equals(other.usuario))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

This last class is used for the trick of simulating a many to many relation. I have followed this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Comment: I don't understand how you can have a many-to-many relation in a select input... At time t, selected elements will always belong to an entity (User). Or maybe I misunderstand your question

Comment: Yes, this is a many to many relation but Im using just one direction One User -> many roles, but in my database I have a table that has idUser and idRol. I have edited the question with a solution but still wanna know if spring gives any facility to achieve what I want

Comment: Ok now I understand. I don't think that spring has something specific to achieve this... But you should probably do that behavior on the controller side and then return a array of roles id that belong to the lists of users. Then use that array to check if options should be selected. It makes the view clearer, I usually try to avoid to many embedded JSTL tag, it gets difficult to understand

Comment: yes.. thats what Im doing right now. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Now things are getting clearer... As I mentioned in my answer, the objects should be of the same type, which they aren't in yuor case (`Rol` != `Usario_Rol`). Probably the easiest thing to do, is create a custom form object for this form, which only contains the necessary data, in the controller you can do the conversion from/to your actual domain object. That way you can expose a list of selected `Rol` objects instead of the intermediate objects. (Or create a wrapper/proxy for your current object).

Comment: I think I prefer to leave my jsp with the foreach tags than create a new form object, is less code. Dont you think?

Answer (score 5):

Why are you writing your own? Spring should be able to do that for you. Instead of a `<c:forEach />` replace that whole block with a `<form options .. />` tags. Spring will then be able to do the selection itself (you might need a [Converter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) or [PropertyEditor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion) for that).

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="roles" items="${roles}" itemLabel="nombre" itemValue="id" />
```

Something along these lines...

Links:

1. Form Options [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options)
2. Form Select [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.select)
3. [Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag)

Comment: I already did that but is not working, Im not getting the options selected. I use that in a new form, but in my edit form is not working. Dont know why...

Comment: As mentioned you probably need a custom Converter (check the links in my answer) for that. Also the `roles` path (attribute on your user object I guess) should contain the same type as in the list with all the roles available, else it isn't going to work.

Comment: ok, let me explain better. I have 2 forms, a new form and edit form. New form is just a blank form, with no information on it. An edit form is get filled with user information once you submit a new form. So, if in the new form my user has selected rol "Administrador" (Admin in English), when I edit the form I need rol "Administrador" been selected. <select ..> <option selected="selected" value=1>Administrador</option><option value=2>Usuario</option>...</select>. Why should I use javascript for that??

Comment: The select and options should be a one-liner, modified my answer. You don't need javascript (confused this with another question).

Comment: Also for it to work correctly make sure you havea proper hashcode and equals implementation for your `Rol` object, as the select tag uses the `Collection.contains` method to check if something exists.

Comment: I do have equals and hashcode implemented as well. I can show the classes if you want.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the question, if you find something wrong let me know please. Maybe is not working because of the tutorial that I followed, dont know..

Answer (score 4):

If you use this:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="roles" items="${roles}" itemLabel="nombre" itemValue="id" />
```

you need to override toString() method of Usuario_Rol, in the right way for your class, to ensure that Spring pre-selects the initial values for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, what you want is your Spring tag to generate HTML like this one:

```
    <select id="roles" name="roles multiple="multiple">
       <option value="1">Administrador</option>
       <option value="2">Usuario avanzado</option>
       <option value="3" selected="selected">Usuario </option>
       <option value="4" selected="selected">Invitado</option>
    </select>
```

As you can see, two values are selected ("Usuario" and "Invitado").

The "roles" model attribute that "path" refers to in your Spring tag has be an array instead of a single value. It's as easy as that. Please be aware that I set the array by hand in my controller. I am not familiar with the implications on the ORM side of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to expect output like this:

```
<select id="roles" name="roles" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1">Administrador</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">Usuario avanzado</option>
 <option value="3" selected="selected">Usuario </option>
</select>
```

In model class you can create method for "roles" which should return array. Add your business complexity in that method.

```
public Integer[] getRoles(){
    Integer[] selectedRoles = {2,3};
    return selectedRoles;
}
```

In JSP:

```
<form:select multiple="true" path="roles">
    <form:options items="${...}" itemValue="..." itemLabel="..."/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

using like this works

```html
<form:select multiple="true" path="membros">
<form:options items="${membroList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="nome">/form:options>
</form:select>
```

the your path="membros" can be set<?>