# In Spring MVC JSP How to retrieve multiple member values from a slingle selected object in a form:select

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp-tags

```
<form:form id="UserSkill" action="../${action}" method="POST" >
    <form:select path="skillID">
        <form:option value="0" >${skillListPrompt}</form:option>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${skills}">
            <form:option value="${item.id}" >${item.name}</form:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
</form:form>
```

`UserSkill` is the main model object for the form and `skills` is an array list added as an object to the view.

I have another member of `userSkill`, `owner` and I want a neat way to, in addition to what I do above, set `owner` to `item.creator` from the same item when the user selects just one item from the drop down and submits the form.  But I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728678/spring-formselect-multiple-selected-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331532/multiple-select-in-spring-3-0-mvc

Comment: Sorry, it's probably just me, but aren't those posts about the user making multiple selections from the drop down?  Maybe I'm missing something or haven't properly explained what I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: yes they are, you need to use `multiple="true"`

Comment: Maybe what I'm trying to do is in some way inappropriate, but that's not what I'm trying to do.  I want the user to make just one selection then in a neat way I want userSkill.skillID to be set to item.id and userSkill.owner to be set to item.creator, for the one item for the one selection. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite the title.